# Auto restart IIS Website from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have an ASP.Net application used by many customers installed on their own servers. Because it is installed on their end with each having different databases and URL bindings etc I created a console application a while ago that gets a zip file and extracts it to c:\inetpub location to append the latest application changes.  This console app is added to scheduled tasks to create an automated update.

Obviously when anyone accesses the site for the first time after it does this they have to wait a little longer whilst the site rebuilds.  I changed the console application to include a Process.Start(urlofapp) so that it should hopefully do this as part of the update so the next morning that first user doesn't have to wait for the rebuild.

I have tested it ok running myself but not yet released as my concern is that this url process is kept open. Can anyone enlighten me as to whether this would be the case as I don't want this to happen or can give me any ideas as to how to rebuild the site manually as part of the console app.

Comment: Why don't you replace Process.Start() with a simple WebRequest?

Comment: Why use Process.Start? There are plenty of ways to make an HTTP request programatically to a website without actually launching a browser.

Comment: Yes good point, I was clearly thinking browser before simple URL. Will try first.

Comment: I have done a simple WebClient DownloadString which worked great and the console app closed as expected when finished, thanks.  Should I delete this question or can one of you post an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 0):

IIS has had an auto-start apps feature for quite some time. You just have to enable it. You can find more info from [the Gu](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series), and [the IIS site](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization).

Comment: You should include the relevant directions in your answer, rather than relying on external links.

Comment: I assume you mean the Application Initialisation. I tried this and whilst it is included on IIS8+, IIS7.5 doesn't have it and I had issues installing the extension on many servers

Answer (score -1):

Safer instead to use a start page which loads everything on the server in the background. If you do this logic in an async method which in turn is called from an MVC controller for example then this can potentially run whilst the main page has finished. Alternatively use a threaded Task and show a start page that is only returned whilst setup is taking place.

Comment: That's not how IIS works.  The MVC controller is going to be part of the updated DLLs - the very same DLLs that IIS has detected have changed so it's going to JIT everything before any start page let alone a controller will run

Comment: that's why i said thread it instead of letting it lock up the request.

Comment: Are you suggesting to do this on the original asp.net application?

Comment: yes. Pull and thread, it should be able to run in the background with a temporary page, then when the thread completes, you can return the normal page content.

Comment: But the moment any DLL is copied into the bin folder any code stops working to extract the rest of the zip contents. Also to automate the update I would have to put in some form of timer which I don't want to add into a very busy web application,

Comment: When I've done this before I've loaded the dll using reflection from a thread, pulled out the interface implementing class and run the code, then closed it all off and completed the thread. You can instead do this through a process, but it gets messier. Long and the short of it is that if you need to stop the web site to do updates then you should do this outside the webapp but you're asking how to do it from WITHIN the webapp. The best way I can see for you is to simply use the external app option, i.e. run a process outside of the main IIS process.

Comment: No I said I created a console application to download a zip and extract updates to the inetpub location. I am already doing it separately. No mention of doing it within the original web app.

Comment: _"that's why i said thread it instead of letting"_ - if you can explain how you can create and run a thread in ASP.NET app **A** before **before** .NET JIT's **A**, I'll give you _one billion dollars_